# Godot - Object doesn't stop when colliding with other object

Tags: collision-detection, tile, godot, gdscript

I am learning Godot Engine and scripting, and I tried to create a simple game, where a ball moves and collides with other objects. I attached collision and static body to the sprite, but it does not detect collision with any other object. Why?

This is the scene:
[image: This is the scene:]

This is the script attached to the ball:

[image: This is the script attached to the ball:]

What is wrong?

Comment: Try colliding with another sprite, or anything else, and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, I needed to use the `move()` function, that was created for collisions.